# Why Generic with multiple type trigger compile-time error in visual code

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-typescript

I am trying to create a generic type function that take one parameter with multiple.

This should be easy but when I mix some types together then I get `compile-time` in visual code.

See my example below

This work..

```js
class Test<T>{
    GetValue(value: string|boolean|number|undefined) {
        return value;
    }
}

new Test<Item>().getValue(4)
new Test<Item>().getValue(true)
```

This also work

```js
    class Test<T>{
        GetValue<B>(value: (x: T) => B) {
            return value;
        }
    }

    new Test<Item>().getValue(x=> x.name)
```

But this dose not work. Why?

```js
    class Test<T>{
        GetValue<B>(value: (x: T) => B|string|boolean|number|undefined) {
            return value;
        }
    }
    // this work
    new Test<Item>().getValue(x=> x.name)
    
    // this do not work Why is that?
    new Test<Item>().getValue(true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator precedence issue:

```
(x: T) => B|string|boolean|number|undefined
```

should be:

```
((x: T) => B)|string|boolean|number|undefined
```

Otherwise parameter `value` is considered a function that returns `B|string|boolean|number|undefined`

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=73&pln=6&pc=28#code/AQiWDsBcFMCcDMCGBjawCSMC2wDeAoEIkcRLaALmAGdJYIBzQkAX2eHeGQBtFrrgAFWi0APIIB8BYsQbRIANUTcArtFEAhCQAoAbsrVVt2gB5VBASmABeCcA0WAPrXrgGjgEYB7L92iJwR3AVLA84RxVwABNoeAhoKKtpGRTYeRVYcGB9VWgAbk5iNiLOAHpS4EgAC1ABAHcvWABrTnBoOqERSFFMaCwdCwA6OUUDaFNbYBNB0nILTjKK6trgKK9gcC9IYAbm4AB1KoBPYBXqxEgAflb2zrFe-u0hkaVc7To1CyA)